# Is .NET for Apache Spark in Preview?

Tags: c#, azure-databricks, .net-spark

I have read many articles while exploring Azure Data Factory and Azure Databricks. I stumbled upon a article(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/spark/how-to-guides/databricks-deploy-methods) where it is mentioned in the notes that .NET for Apache Spark is in preview.

Just wanted to know if .NET for Apache Spark is still in Preview and not available generally for production use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET for Apache Spark](https://github.com/dotnet/spark) is actively developed project with many features. According to [Official page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/data/spark) at Microsoft website it's generally available and definitely worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

The 1.0 release is being tracked here - https://github.com/dotnet/spark/milestone/4